# Does terraform provide a resource to create emr notebooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, terraform, amazon-emr, terraform-provider-aws

I have an transient Emr cluster up and ready, I want to run a simple pyspark script on the emr notebook.

Is there any way to create and modify the emr notebook through terraform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
As far as i know, AWS says "You create an EMR notebook using the Amazon EMR console. Creating notebooks using the AWS CLI or the Amazon EMR API is not supported." [AWS Documentation on creating EMR Notebook][1]

You can create a notebook via console, the notebook will be stored in S3 as .ipynb, by giving the relative path, you can execute notebook on the cluster. Refer boto3 for more info [Boto3 Documentation][2]  


  [1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-create.html
  [2]: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.start_notebook_execution
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create and modify an EMR cluster from Terraform and choose which tools will be installed, but this seems like the "hard way".  Easier would be a Sagemaker Notebook or using the new Glue Databrew tool.